# Why would Eclipse not be able to include a file when running a PHPUnit test?

Tags: eclipse, phpunit

I have the following **class** and **unit test** in a PHP project in Eclipse:

[image]

I know my **unit test works** as I can run it at the command line:

[image]

Now I want to run this test from Eclipse. I set up PHP Unit in Eclipse like this:

[image]

However, when I run the PHPUnit tests:

[image]

It tells me that it can't include the class file:

```
/usr/bin/php -c /var/folders/UA/UAv38snBHd0QMgEPMCmM9U+++TM/-Tmp-/zend_debug/session4910937990995915704.tmp -d asp_tags=off /Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.phpunit_0.5.0.R20101103000000/php/tools/phpunit.php --log-junit /var/folders/UA/UAv38snBHd0QMgEPMCmM9U+++TM/-Tmp-/pti_phpunit/phpunit.xml /Volumes/data/domains/et/extjslayout/phpunittest/tests
PHP Warning:  include_once(../Product.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Volumes/data/domains/et/extjslayout/phpunittest/tests/ProductTest.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '../Product.php' for inclusion (include_path='/usr/local/PEAR') in /Volumes/data/domains/et/extjslayout/phpunittest/tests/ProductTest.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Product' not found in /Volumes/data/domains/et/extjslayout/phpunittest/tests/ProductTest.php on line 9
```

**Why would PHPUnit be able to find the class when run from the command line but not when run from Eclipse?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start something from the command line, the "current directory" has a well-defined meaning: It's the directory where you started the command.

In Eclipse, what is the "current directory"? It's probably the directory from which you started Eclipse or maybe the folder in which Eclipse is installed.

I haven't used PHP in Eclipse before but for other languages, I can set the current directory in the launch config somewhere. If that doesn't work, define a variable which points to your project and then use absolute paths (using that variable as a starting point).

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem. Found only solution by creating tests with internal PHPUnit wizard like at this screenshot:
[image: phpunit test wizard. eclipse]

Source: [HowTo create a Test Case Class from a PHP Class](http://www.phpsrc.org/projects/4/wiki/howto_create_a_test_case_class_from_a_php_class)

But following investigate show that your test case file should contain reference to tested code for example like this: `require_once 'C:\Apache2\htdocs\jobeet\src\Ibw\JobeetBundle\Utils\Jobeet.php';`

Other experiments with plugin config not bringing luck. So in my opinion PHPUnit from PHP Tools not well developed plugin. Consider using MakeGood plugin as better alternative.